# Is there bitbucket integration for emacs?

Tags: git

I am looking for listing pull requests on bitbucket that I created from emacs. I found this https://github.com/tjaartvdwalt/bitbucket.el, which seems to be incomplete. Is there any other package out there which will full fill my requirement?

Comment: Can you add which specific features you're thinking about in your question? Things would be much clearer if you mentioned you're interested in things like being able to manage pull requests.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the short answer, at present (2018-06), is "no".

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: My read of the question is that noorul is looking for an emacs package which provides a means of viewing, in emacs, pull requests for a given bitbucket project -- perhaps something similar to the `bitbucket-issues-list` function provided by https://github.com/tjaartvdwalt/bitbucket.el. My answer simply is an indication that, to my knowledge, no such emacs package, at present, provides such a function for pull requests.